# Как скопировать содержимое каталога в другой каталог?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

```
$ cp -r dir1/. dir2
```

Команду то я нашёл. Но мне не понятно откуда взялся синтаксис `/.`? Это что то вроде регулярного выражения? В [мануале](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/cp.1.html) информации нет. Спасибо.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Каждый каталог содержит в себе два обязательных элемента:

- псевдокаталог `..`, обозначающий каталог выше по дереву директорий (даже в `/` есть `/..`, но обозначает всё так же `/`)
- псевдокаталог `.`, обозначающий самого себя. Например, используется в командах для обозначения пути от текущего каталога: `./configure` вызывающий скрипт `configure` в текущей директории.

Таким образом, в команде `cp -r dir1/. dir2` аргумент `dir/.` является просто необычной записью `cp -r dir1 dir2`. Можно писать и как-то экзотично:

```
cp -r dir1/././../dir1/./ dir2
```

---

Однако поведение `cp` неожиданно отличается в случае если `dir2` уже существует, а не будет создан командой `cp`.

```
cp -r dir1 dir2
# и аналогично cp -r dir1/ dir2
```

Для существующего `dir2` создаст копию директории `dir1` в `dir2/dir1` вместо копирования содержимого `dir1` в `dir2`.

Тогда как

```
cp -r dir1/. dir2
```

Именно будет копировать содержимое `dir1` в `dir2`.

Это неочевидная особенность реализации именно `cp`. Например, `rsync` такими странными вещами не занимается и следующие записи эквивалентны:

```
rsync -a dir1 dir2/
rsync -a dir1/. dir2/
```

(но `rsync` при этом будет различаться поведением для записи `dir2/` и `dir2` для существующей директории, лучше указывать как подсказывает автокомплит, оканчивая путь `/`)

Comment: `cp -r dir1 dir2` - скопирует каталог dir1 в dir2, а `cp -r dir1/. dir2` - скопирует содержимое каталога dir1 в dir2. Выходит это не просто необычная запись. Кто то писал что это специфический синтаксис `cp` https://askubuntu.com/a/86891

Comment: хм. Интересно. Если dir2 существует, то поведение действительно различается. Хм

Comment: Есть какие то расширенные мануалы в которых это описано?

Comment: Исходники этих утилит, видимо. В ARGV передаются как есть оба варианта записи.